# Do comments cost gas?

Tags: solidity, natspec

It is a simple question that I couldn't find an answer to with a quick google and stack search. I believe they won't cost gas but I just wanted to make sure if they do or don't.

Comment: They don't cost gas, but they influence the bytecode metadata hash.

Comment: It would be good if you accept an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

In Ethereum, what causes gas usage are eth transactions, bytecode and data storing, and also bytecode execution, so since comments don't generate any of those, they do not cause any gas costs.

All about gas in Ethereum Docs: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/

Answer (score 0):

no

Every operation you perform costs gas other than that won't cost you anything